# Typescript enum, used from implementation and interfaces

Tags: enums, typescript

I have the following, in CommandEnum.ts:

```
export enum CommandEnum {
    createProject,
    renameProject,
    hablaBabla
}
```

in a module which I am able to reference from implementation code, using

```
import {CommandEnum} from '../server/contracts/CommandEnum'

let x = CommmandEnum.hablaBabla
```

The enum file is compiled into a javascript function with export logic, in CommandEnum.js.

This now works fine, but I want to reference this enum in my interfaces as well, I try:

```
/// <reference path="../contracts/CommandEnum.ts" />
namespace ValueTypes {

    export interface Command {
        type : CommandEnum;
        referenceId : string;
    }
}
```

Now, this reference does not import the CommandEnum type, but some of the other combinations of modules / namespace / export default I have tried does.  **I can get the reference syntax to work, but not the module syntax and the other way around - but not both.**

Is this actually possible? Using an enum from a pure definitions interface file seems like a very common scenario. But when the interface is implemented the enum must be available in "function form" and these two models does not seem to combine?

I had the same problem with classes, which I wanted to namespace, .Net-style - which I had to give up. Classes, however, are not referenced in my interfaces - enums are.

I work with node.js and compile to individual files, not a single concated output.

Answer (score 3):

> This now works fine, but I want to reference this enum in my interfaces as well

You can move stuff from a `module` into the global namespace use `declare global`

E.g. `myEnumGlobalDeclare.ts`

```
import {MyEnum as MyEnumModule} from "./myEnum";
declare global {
   declare var MyEnum: typeof MyEnumModule;
}
```

E.g. `myEnumGlobalDefine.ts`

```
import {MyEnum as MyEnumModule} from "./myEnum";
MyEnum = MyEnumModule;
```

Or something similar ^. Of course this means your runtime should support *global* augmentation e.g. in nodejs you need to use `globals` and in browsers `window`.

## More

I definitely do not recommend going down this path. Instead create a global `types.ts` module and just use that everywhere. E.g. alm has this file : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/master/src/common/types.ts

Comment: @baserat, thank you.  I take it you recommend a single contract file for the project / subdomain - with all enums and interfaces?  This would probably solve the problem but I believe it could lead to very heavy type files in some projects...  For now I'll just use strings in the interfaces and enums in the implementation.